# Only First JSF Controller is Created. Others Are Ignored

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My first time trying Java and this error is rather strange and I seem to be the only one having the problem on this planet.

I have two web pages:

```
<h:link outcome="index">Home</h:link>
<h:link outcome="about">About</h:link>
```

I have two controllers, shown below in the order I created them in package `Controller`:

HomeController.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class HomeController implements Serializable{

    public HomeController() {
        System.out.println("Home Controller Created......");
    }
}
```

AboutController.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AboutController implements Serializable{

    public AboutController() {
        System.out.println("About Controller Created......");
    }
}
```

If I visit `home.xhtml`, I see **Home Controller Created......** but I don't see any message on `about.xhtml`. The Controller doesn't get called even when I `Debug` with NetBeans.

Comment: show your home.xhtml and about.xhtml

Comment: i think you are confusing JSF and MVC, JSF dosn't need controlers, your should start with some tutorials

Comment: The `AboutController` wont get generated until you use it in any JSF file.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt is right. Put a string property on `AboutController` and reference it in home.xhtml and you will see that `AboutConroller` is instantiated because it is needed. This is usually the desired behavior.